# Fetch with Svelte vs Sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm following along with the svelte tutorial here:

https://svelte.dev/repl/a74f1ed8e3eb4aec82cb743e13443ee4?version=3.48.0

Essentially, it includes `App.Svelte` file and `fetch.js` import file.

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export default function (url) {
    const loading = writable(false)
    const error = writable(false)
    const data = writable({})
    
    async function get() {
        loading.set(true)
        error.set(false)
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url)
            data.set(await response.json())
        } catch(e) {
            error.set(e)
        }
        loading.set(false)
    }
    
    get()
    
    return [ data, loading, error, get]
}
```

```html
<script>
    let url = "https://www.swapi.tech/api/people/1"
    
    import fetchStore from './fetch.js'
    const [data, loading, error, get] = fetchStore(url)
</script>

<button on:click={get}>
    Fetch again
</button>

{#if $loading}
    Loading: {$loading}
{:else if $error}
    Error: {$error}
{:else}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify($data, null, 2)}</pre>
{/if}
```

This all works as expected in Svelte.

However, If move the code into a Sveltekit app I'm getting the following errors in my VS Code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've put the `fetch.js` file in the root of the `src` directory and renamed the `App.Svelte` to `getData.Svelte which is in the` routes`directory below the`src`.

It seems that things work differently between Svelte vs Sveltekit which make the tutorial confusing. Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: the code is not entirely the same it seems, in the SvelteKit version you are importing from a file called `fetchdata`(not fetch.js) and you are destructuring the import.  That makes it difficult to compare the two.

Comment: Arh yes - I updated the file and the screenshot. They should be exactly the same now.

Comment: Is there no additional information on the error except for the underlines?

Comment: Added more information for highlighted errors.

Comment: Better add @name, otherwise there's no notification since you're commenting your own question... These errors aren't just visual and the code doesn't run?

Comment: @Corrl - The code actually runs OK, it just seams to be VS Code that's complaining about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a TypeScript problem. I'll spare you the technical detail and just tell you a quick fix: instead of returning an array, return an object instead.

So in `fetchStore` function you `return { data, loading, error, get }`. And in svelte component you read like `const { data, loading, error, get } = fetchStore(url)`. Basically change bracket `[]` to brace`{}` and the error will go away.